# How would i execute a php while loop a specific number of times?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

im using bootstrap and my main index page is in php, i have been trying to dynamically display data from my database but i only want to display 5 of the rows in my database table.

```
      echo '<ul class="sort" id="rank_ul">';
      $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM IFC  ORDER BY votes DESC");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
                 {?>
           <li id="li<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                <div class="tut-img">
            <img src="<?php echo $row['img']?>" width="50" height="70" alt="<?php echo $row['title']?>" />
              <div class="drag-label"></div>
                  </div>
     <div class="title">
   <a href="<?php echo $row['url']?>" target="_blank" title=""><?php echo $row['title']?></a>
                                            </div>
                                             </li>
                                                   <?php }?>
                                        </ul>
```

essentially my code is creating as many list items as there are rows in my data, but i would like to make it stop creating list items at a specific number of times, the issue i had was that i wanted to keep it in descending order and switching from a while loop to a for loop or do-while didnt create the list items.

Comment: use a LIMIT in your query

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and best) way would be to add a [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause to your query like so:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM IFC ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 5");
```

As a side note, I highly recommend using either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the old, deprecated MySQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem in you PHP code, of course, but the cleanest way would be to **only fetch the entries from the database you actually need**.

Using MySQL's [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause, you can specify how many rows you want to select:

```
SELECT * FROM IFC  ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 50
```

In this case, only 50 rows will be selected and echoed by your code.

---

On a side node, please be aware that [the **mysql PHP extension is deprecated** since PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Not only cleanest, but most efficient. If you always just selected all values from a database and iterated over the first x of them that's a ton of overhead that you could avoid on the mysql layer.

Answer (score 0):

append LIMIT 5 on your SQL query.